# How to exports a class and require it in React.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example

component.jsx

```
exports.a = class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1 style={style1}>Hello world,{this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
```

main.js

```
var Hello = require('./component.jsx');
function main() {
    ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('app'));
}
```

I using webpack, and module.exports,ES6 export works find.I just want to know how to do it in the exports way.

Comment: This has nothing to do with React nor with ES6.

Comment: yes,the above is incorrect version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `module.exports = class Hello extends React.Component { ... }`

If you use `exports.a`, then you'll need to write `var Hello = require('./component.jsx').a` (notice the `.a`)

Answer (score 1):

Use this syntax:

```
export default class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
   return <h1 style={style1}>Hello world,{this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
```

You can read up on the ES6 export syntax on this page:
http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-es6-modules/

Comment: You can use `export` more than once. The trick is not to use `default`.

If you use `default`, then you can import it normally: `var Hello = require('./component.jsx')`. 

But if you use something like `export class Hello ...` (notice I didn't use `default`), then you need to import it differently:

1. `import { Hello } from './component.jsx'`
2. `var Hello = require('./component.jsx').Hello`